# How to disable buildNumber increment in specific configurations?

Tags: sbt, sbt-buildinfo

I'm using the sbt-buildinfo plugin to track version number in my multiple-projects environment. The plugin is fine. But I want to increment buildNumber only in specific build, i.e. 'assembly' in 'production' configuration. Unfortunately, this value being increased each time I build my project, even if I just want to generate the scaladoc.

How to point the sbt-buildinfo not to increase the arbitrary value or change the buildInfoKeys set for the configuration and task?